# Dynamic segment_1 in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

This is a pretty simple question, I just can't seem to find the information on it.  In expression engine, is it possible for {segment_1} to be a dynamic variable.  I.E. if I wanted to take my URL structure from:
http://www.whatever.com/category/football/green-bay/
to:
http://www.whatever.com/football/green-bay/
I don't want to actually create the directory for football within my code(as this is just an example, and the amount of base categories is in the hundreds), I just want it to map to my templates/category page.

I know this could probably be accomplished somehow through mod_rewrite, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm trying to see if there's a built in way in Expression Engine to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the sort of functionality that the [MD Detect Pagetype plugin](http://masugadesign.com/the-lab/scripts/md-detect-page-type/) offers. The plugin "listens" to a certain URL segment to determine what type of page is being displayed. It then gives you access to the following conditionals:

```
{exp:md_detect_page_type url_segment="{segment_3}"}

  {if pagination_page}This is a Paginated Page{/if}
  {if category_page}This is a Category Page{/if}
  {if yearly_archive_page}This is a Yearly Archive Page{/if}

{/exp:md_detect_page_type}
```

Visit the website linked above to download and find out more about the free plugin.

Comment: I think that's more about page type than the segments.  I'm specifically talking about the 1st segment.  I don't think there is a way to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Ahhh, yes. I did a bit more poking around and found an [EE forum thread](http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/86353/) about this very issue. Seems like it's not possible out of the box, but it _is_ doable by using the `{exp:query}` tag (albeit, with some possible issues).